# Trying to block visitors using regex on fail2ban

Tags: regex, nginx, fail2ban

I am receiving a large number of request for PHP files that does not exist in my wordpress.
They show up in nginx error logs as following two examples:

```
2019/06/24 03:16:43 [error] 4201#4201: *17573871 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.68.189.50, server: mywebsite.net, request: "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "mywebsite.net"
2019/06/24 03:16:43 [error] 4201#4201: *17573871 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.68.189.50, server: mywebsite.net, request: "POST /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "mywebsite.net"
```

I have tried making a noscript filter.

In file /etc/fail2ban/jail.local I put:

```
[nginx-noscript]

enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = nginx-noscript
logpath  = /var/log/nginx/error.log
maxretry = 2
```

In File /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-noscript.conf I put:

```
[Definition]

failregex = \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ (FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script:)

ignoreregex =
```

But this filter is not catching these type of 404s. After `systemctl restart fail2ban` the fail2ban logs shows these error messages.

```
2019-06-24 16:11:05,548 fail2ban.filter         [6182]: ERROR   No failure-id group in '\[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ (FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script:)'
2019-06-24 16:11:05,548 fail2ban.transmitter    [6182]: WARNING Command ['set', 'nginx-noscript', 'addfailregex', '\\[error\\] \\d+#\\d+: \\*\\d+ (FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script:)'] has failed. Received RegexException('No failure-id group in \'\\[error\\] \\d+#\\d+: \\*\\d+ (FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script:)\'',)
2019-06-24 16:11:05,549 fail2ban                [6182]: ERROR   NOK: ('No failure-id group in \'\\[error\\] \\d+#\\d+: \\*\\d+ (FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script:)\'',)
```

What am I doing wrong. What will be the full regex for such nginx error logs.

Comment: Remove `^` and `$` anchors, they require the full string match.

Comment: It still does not work @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: It [does here](https://regex101.com/r/IhtGrh/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There is some other problem in the fail2ban regex configuration. I have added those error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (for fail2ban >= 0.10):

```
failregex = ^\s*\[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: [^"]*" while reading response header from upstream, client: <ADDR>
```

If you have older versions (0.9 or below), use `<HOST>` instead of `<ADDR>` (and better disable DNS-lookup for jail with `usedns = no`).